# Use v_for without v-bind:key as shown in the docs?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

The vue docs https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html say I can do this:

```
<div v-for="(value, name) in object">
  {{ name }}: {{ value }}
</div>
```

But when I do that I get:

```
Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

  7:5  error  Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives  vue/require-v-for-key
```

I can work around by saying

```
    <div v-for="(value, name) in object" v-bind:key="name">
```

Are the docs wrong? What am I missing?

```
air:v0 crb$ vue --version
@vue/cli 4.5.6
```

Command is 'npm run serve' which runs 'vue-cli-service serve'

The whole file:

```
<template>
  <div class="foo">
    <h1>foo Component</h1>
    <!--
    <div v-for="(value, name) in object" v-bind:key="name">
    --> 
    <div v-for="(value, name) in object">
      {{ name }}: {{ value }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
        data() {
                return {
                        object: { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 }
                }
        }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This is from eslint. You can tell it to ignore the rule (the name is in the end of the error) and it’ll let you do it without

Comment: Ah, yes, thanks. I'll try that.

Comment: Trying to figure out how to do that. The docs suggested adding "  "lintOnSave": false
" to ~/..vuerc but that didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: This probably helps: https://vuejs.github.io/eslint-plugin-vue/user-guide/#usage You can just disable that one rule in it and let everything else be checked

Answer (score 2):

As you can see ESLint gave you the name of the rule `vue/require-v-for-key`, so you can just disable it.

In your `./eslintrc.js` file, add the following rule and set it to `warn` or `off`:

```
{  
  ...
  rules: {
    'vue/require-v-for-key': 'warn',
  }
}
```

- `warn` - will only show you a warning rather than throwing the error. This is preferable to `off` because the warnings will remind you to fix these issues before publishing your app.
- `off` - will completely disable that specific rule and will not warn you about it, hence you might forget to set `:key` attribute everywhere which might lead to worse performance, since Vue uses keys for optimizations.

You can also install the [eslint-plugin-only-warn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-only-warn) plugin if you want to switch all rules to warnings:

```
{  
  ...
  plugins: [
    'only-warn'
  ],
  rules: {
    'vue/require-v-for-key': 'warn',
  }
}
```

Comment: @CharlieBurns You are welcome. I'm also always get annoyed by these ESLint errors because they pop up when you are experimenting and prototyping the app and don't let you continue, so I ended up installing the `only-warn` plugin, which switches all rules to warnings, which you can then fix whenever you want it, rather than when ESLint tells you to (I updated the answer and added the link)